# Always setting path across users in R

Tags: r, directory, filepath

I have a simple question, how does one always set the same path across a user base. For instance, I use
getwd() to get my path: "C:/Users/Genetics/Documents". Can I set in my script, no matter who uses this to go to "C:/Users/Any User/Desktop"? I want to make this fluid, so I don't have correct this for each person.

```
ALWAYS_TO_DEKSTOP<- Some way to be flexible to Desktop across users and systems???
PathName <- paste(ALWAYS_TO_DEKSTOP,"BIDS/IDs.txt", sep="");
read.table(PathName, header=T);
```

Comment: `file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),"Desktop")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE")` to get the path to the users home directory. Then append the folder you want, e.g. `Documents` so you get

```
file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),"Documents")
[1] "C:\\Users\\my_username/Documents"
```

Notice the escaped backslashes on Windows. You can change that with `normalizePath()`, see `?normalizePath` for reasons why you might want that.

```
normalizePath(path = file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),"Documents"), winslash = "/")
[1] "C:/Users/my_username/Documents"
```

There are other paths available in `Sys.getenv()`, such as (on Windows)

```
ProgramData                                    C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles                                   C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)                              C:\Program Files (x86)
RTOOLS40_HOME                                  C:\rtools40
```